# jquery.ajax is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug

I trying to get webpage's html by using ajax function like below.

But it always alert 'error'.

I can't understand why it occur.

I also checked http protocol status using firebug in firefox.

It show me a 200 value.

Plz let me know how to debug it.

[image]

```
     $.ajax({
      url: "http://news.naver.com/main/home.nhn",        

      success: function() { alert('success'); },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); }
    });
```

Comment: That script will only work on `http://news.naver.com`. Are you running it on that domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is naver.com your site? If not, then you can't retrieve data from it using AJAX, since you can only make AJAX calls to the same domain as the page you're on.

If that's not the problem, then you'll need to provide more details - like what's inside your arguments in your error function.

Comment: You can see from the headers that the request came from cloud9ide.com, so problem would be as you've suggested, cross domain AJAX

Comment: @Procrammer Good call, didn't notice that.